# How do I check if the first occurrence of a number equals to x?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, nested-lists

I'm am trying to find a way to check if the first first a number in a nested list equals to x.

> check(X,L), X= is a number and Y is a nested list.

```
check(2,[a,b[g,4],y,8]).
false

check(2,[a,b[g,2],y,8]).
true
```

It seems that recursion would do best. But I still do not understand how to approach it with recursion in Prolog. 
I had this idea of flattening the nested list and then check if first element is a number and if it equals to X. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea must be refined. Some code is needed to match the *first* occurrence. I would 'cheat':

```
check(X,L) :- flatten(L,F), include(number,F,[X|_]).
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be nicely done with simple recursion:

```
check(X,[X|_]) :- number(X).
check(X,[NL|_]) :- is_list(NL), check(X, NL).
check(X,[V|L]) :- not(number(V)), check(X, L).
```

**UPDATE:**

This fixes problem found by @CappelliC:

```
check(X,[X|_]) :- number(X).
check(X,[V|L]) :- not(number(V)), not(is_list(V)), check(X, L).
check(X,[NL|L]) :- is_list(NL), append(NL,L,BL), check(X, BL).
```

Results:

```
?- check(2,[a,b,[g,4],y,8]).
false.

?- check(2,[a,b,[g,2],y,8]).
true .
```

Comment: seems wrong, as it succeeds also when X is not the first

Comment: @CapelliC, are you sure? I get `false` for `check(2,[1,2]).`.

Comment: @CapelliC, please, provide some example of when my `check/2` works wrong.

Comment: `?- check(2,[a,b,[g,3],y,2]).` answers true